# Java: ArrayOutofBounds Exception when trying to count primes using Sieve

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes

My code compiles without errors, but the in my output I'm getting an ArrayOutofBoundsException for line 37. Everything works except the prime counter. Can anyone see where I made a mistake in this code? The prime counter works in another program I have.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sieve {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //get ceiling on our prime numbers
    int N;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the prime number ceiling: ");
    N = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();

    //init our numbers array, where true denotes prime
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[N];
    isPrime[0] = false;
    for (int c = 1; c < N; c++) {
        isPrime[c] = true;

    }

    //check every number >= 2 for primality
    //first loops, checks to see is numbers are marked
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        if (isPrime[i-1]) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");

            //cross off all subsequent mutliples of
            //second loop, marks all multiples of number
            for (int j = i * 2; j <= N; j += i) {
                isPrime[j-1] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    //counts primes
    int primes = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c <= N; c++) {
        if (isPrime[c]); //error here
        primes++;
    }
    //prints # of primes
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("The number of primes <= " + N + " is " + primes);
}
}
```

Comment: Try `c < N` without the `=`. Remember, arrays are *zero-based* in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop condition is bad

```
for (int c = 0; c <= N; c++) {
```

should be

```
for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
```

as you have an array of dimension N, and the cointng starts from 0.

---

```
for (int c = 1; c < N; c++) {
        isPrime[c] = true;

}
```

This code sets all numbers to be primes.
What you should do is setting every number to be prime, and later setting every multiple of a number to not be prime.

so it would be like

```
Arrays.fill(isPrime, true);
isPrime[0] = false;
for (int x = 1, x < N; x++) {
   for (int y = x; y < N; y+=x) {
      isPrime[y] = false;
   }
}
```

This should be the real sieve algorithm. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: That fixed half of it, thanks! However, now it's saying that the number of primes is whatever N is. Any ideas?

Comment: Also added the prime solution